# How to make a dictionary of dictionaries with multiple lists

Tags: python, dictionary

There is one index list which will be the key of the parent dictionary:

```
index = [1,2,3]
```

and then multiple lists of which will be the child dicts:

```
triangles = [4,5,6]
circles = [7,8,9]
squares = [10,11,12]
```

the sequential elements being the data, resulting in:

```
{1:{'triangles':4, 'circles':7, 'squares': 10},
 2: {'triangles': 5, 'circles': 8, 'squares': 11},
 3: {'triangles': 6, 'circles': 9, 'squares': 12}}
```

how can I do this ?

Do you think easier to do in pandas ?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` the lists, create the subdicts and then zip the subdicts with the indices. No **restrictions** on the indices; they can be non-sequencial/non-numerical:

```
dct =  dict(zip(index, ({'triangles': i, 'circles': j, 'squares': k} 
                          for i,j,k in zip(triangles, circles, squares))))
print(dct)
```

---

```
{1: {'circles': 7, 'squares': 10, 'triangles': 4},
 2: {'circles': 8, 'squares': 11, 'triangles': 5},
 3: {'circles': 9, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 6}}
```

---

On another note, if you only need sequential counts, the index list can be replaced with `enumerate`:

```
dct =  dict(enumerate(({'triangles': i, 'circles': j, 'squares': k} 
                          for i,j,k in zip(triangles, circles, squares)), 1))
```

Comment: that's really an out of the box solution :) +one Sir

Answer (score 1):

Dict comprehnesions to the rescue!
Note, BTW, that the indices stored in `index` seem to be one-based although python lists are zero-based:

```
result =  {i : {'triangles' : triangles[i-1], 'circles' : circles[i-1], 'squares' : squares[i-1]} for i in index}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is with `dict comprehension` :

```
>>> d = {i:{'triangles':triangles[i-1],'circles':circles[i-1],'squares':squares[i-1]} for i in index}

{1: {'circles': 7, 'squares': 10, 'triangles': 4},
 2: {'circles': 8, 'squares': 11, 'triangles': 5},
 3: {'circles': 9, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is very easy and can be achieved with a simple `for`-loop:

```
index = [1,2,3]

triangles = [4,5,6]
circles = [7,8,9]
squares = [10,11,12]

dictionary = {}

for i in range(0, len(index)):
    dictionary[index[i]] = {'triangles':triangles[i], 'circles':circles[i], 'squares':squares[i]}

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

> {1: {'triangles': 4, 'circles': 7, 'squares': 10}, 2: {'triangles': 5, 'circles': 8, 'squares': 11}, 3: {'triangles': 6, 'circles': 9, 'squares': 12}}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
results = {}
for index, item in enumerate(zip(triangles,circles,squares)):
    results.update({index+1:{'triangles':item[0], 'circles':item[1], 'squares':item[2]}})

Out[6]: 
{1: {'circles': 7, 'squares': 10, 'triangles': 4},
 2: {'circles': 8, 'squares': 11, 'triangles': 5},
 3: {'circles': 9, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got a lot of variables and you don't want to hardcode your dictionary comprehension, here is a way.

NOTE: you need to have all variables declared.

Also you need to declare list of variable names.

```
list_of_var_names = ['triangles', 'circles', 'squares']

dict(zip(index, [dict(zip(list_of_var_names, i)) 
             for i in (globals().get(i) for i in list_of_var_names)]))
```

And to divide step by step:

```
In [1]: index = [1,2,3]
   ...:
   ...: triangles = [4,5,6]
   ...: circles = [7,8,9]
   ...: squares = [10,11,12]
   ...:

In [2]: list_of_var_names = ['triangles', 'circles', 'squares']

In [3]: [globals().get(i) for i in list_of_var_names]  # getting list of variable values in list_of_var_names order
Out[3]: [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

In [4]: [dict(zip(list_of_var_names, i)) for i in (globals().get(i) for i in lis
   ...: t_of_var_names)]
Out[4]:
[{'circles': 5, 'squares': 6, 'triangles': 4},
 {'circles': 8, 'squares': 9, 'triangles': 7},
 {'circles': 11, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 10}]

In [5]: dict(zip(index, [dict(zip(list_of_var_names, i))
   ...:                  for i in (globals().get(i) for i in list_of_var_names)]
   ...: ))
   ...:
Out[5]:
{1: {'circles': 5, 'squares': 6, 'triangles': 4},
 2: {'circles': 8, 'squares': 9, 'triangles': 7},
 3: {'circles': 11, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 10}}
```

I want to mention one more time that this solution if good if you get a ton of variables and you don't want explicitly declare dict comprehension. In other cases it would be more suitable and more readable to use other solutions that are presented here.

Answer (score 0):

Another variety using double `zip()` and `dict comprehension`:

```
triangles = [4,5,6]
circles = [7,8,9]
squares = [10,11,12]
index = [1,2,3]

b = {k:{'triangles': x, 'circles': y, 'squares': z} for k, (x,y,z) in zip(
                                  index, zip(triangles, circles, squares))}
print(b)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'circles': 7, 'squares': 10, 'triangles': 4}, 
2: {'circles': 8, 'squares': 11, 'triangles': 5}, 
3: {'circles': 9, 'squares': 12, 'triangles': 6}}
```